# Android Action bar not showing Icons

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, icons

How can i display Icons in Actions bar, here is my code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/search_icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="Search" >
</item>
</menu>
```

and

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater mif = getMenuInflater();
    mif.inflate(R.menu.custom_action_bar,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks for Help !

Comment: Change your activity theme to Holo.Light.

Comment: Where is the change please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using app compat use app:showAsAction

```
<item android:id="@+id/search_icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Search" >
</item>
```

Comment: No problem app compat does not use the default namespace, this is why calling android:showAsAction does nothing for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Manifest.xml File

```
    <activity android:name="your activity name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.Light"></activity>
```